# Magento 2.2.0 - Upgrade / Migrate from Magento 2.1.9

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.2.0

Followed the commands below to upgrade Magento 2.2.0, I am on 2.1.9

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
composer update magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.0
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework-foreign-key[100.2.0, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework-foreign-key[100.2.0, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework-foreign-key[100.1.3, 100.2.0].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.0 requires magento/framework-foreign-key 100.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework-foreign-key[100.2.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.0].
    - Installation request for magento/framework-foreign-key (locked at 100.1.3) -> satisfiable by magento/framework-foreign-key[100.1.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What is magento/framework-foreign-key? Is there anything that needs to be done prior to upgrade?

Comment: This link might help you: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
rm -rf vendor/*
composer update
```

Beware though, many extensions won't work in 2.2.0, you may need to cleanup your composer.json then reinstall the module one by one.

Comment: So many extensions break its unbelievable - had this same issue, same thought process any trouble remove the vendor folder.

Comment: Yeah.. it's quite bad... I am even thinking on staying on 2.1.9 for now..

Comment: 2.1.9 has a lot of bugs

Comment: Yeah... I've ported the fixes manually from 2.2.0 to 2.1.9...

Comment: Also, if have sample-data packages installed, change version to 100.2.* in `composer.json`